# Magento 2 Product editing error: Form\Gallery doesn't extend Element\AbstractElement

Tags: product, error, exception, extend, edit

Today we've updated from version 2.0.6 to 2.1.2, it was everything but flawless. But I've managed to fix all te problems except one:

**When editing a product I receive this error:**

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery doesn'n extend \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?